# Fill in the date gaps from the stuff

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot-table

I have this result, [year.month week] with my query below

```
[2021.12 51],[2021.12 53],[2022.01 1],[2022.01 2],[2022.01 3],[2022.01 5],[2022.01 6],[2022.02 10]
```

My goal is to fill in the gaps of the week, for example:

```
[2021.12 51],**[2021.12 52]**,[2021.12 53],[2022.01 1],[2022.01 2],[2022.01 3],**[2022.01 4]**,[2022.01 5],[2022.01 6],**[2022.01 7]**,**[2022.01 8]**,**[2022.01 9]**,[2022.02 10]
```

How could I do this with my query below:

```
DECLARE
    @startdate datetime,
    @enddate datetime,
    @paramdef nvarchar(max)

    set @startdate = '2021-01-01 00:00:00.000';
    set @enddate = GETDATE();
    set @paramdef = '@startdate datetime, @enddate datetime';

    SELECT STUFF
    (
        (
            SELECT 
                ',' + QUOTENAME( S_FORMATTED_WEEK_MONTH )
            FROM 
                MONITORING
            WHERE 
                S_DATE_TO >= @startdate AND
                S_DATE_TO <= @enddate 
            GROUP BY 
                S_FORMATTED_WEEK_MONTH
            ORDER BY 
                CAST( REPLACE( SUBSTRING(S_FORMATTED_WEEK_MONTH, 1, 7), '.', '' ) AS INT ),
                CAST( REPLACE( SUBSTRING(S_FORMATTED_WEEK_MONTH, 8, 9), '.', '' ) AS INT )
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE 
        ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')  ,1,1,''
    )
```

Comment: Search for calendar table.

Comment: Can you give a sql snippet? thanks Dale

Answer (score 0):

you can use the below calendar table approach to get the list of weeknumbers as per your format.

```sql
DECLARE @StartDate DATE = '2021-01-01'
DECLARE @EndDate DATE = getdate()

;WITH Cal(n) AS
(
SELECT 0 UNION ALL SELECT n + 1 FROM Cal
WHERE n < DATEDIFF(DAY, @StartDate, @EndDate)
),
FnlDt(d,y,m,w) AS
(
SELECT DATEADD(DAY, n, @StartDate)
      , year(DATEADD(DAY, n, @StartDate))
      , month(DATEADD(DAY, n, @StartDate)) 
      , datepart(week,DATEADD(DAY, n, @StartDate)) FROM Cal
)
select
string_agg(weekarr,',') as concat_weekarr
from
(SELECT concat('[',y,'.',m,' ',w,']') as weekarr
FROM fnlDt
group by y,m,w
) as dt
option(maxrecursion 32767)
```

> [2021.1 1],[2021.1 2],[2021.1 3],[2021.1 4],...